# Anonymous YouTube playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

Under <kbd>Creator Studio</kbd>, <kbd>Video Manager</kbd>, <kbd>Playlists</kbd>,
<kbd>New playlist</kbd>, a new playlist can be created. However this requires
logging in.

Can a YouTube playlist be created without logging in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get all the video IDs, then create a URL like so:

```
http://youtube.com/watch_videos?video_ids=AAAAAAAAAAA,BBBBBBBBBBB,CCCCCCCCCCC,DDDDDDDDDDD
```

It will redirect you to a link like this:

```
http://youtube.com/watch?v=AAAAAAAAAAA&list=EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

If you want to share, you can shorten it to this:

```
http://youtube.com/playlist?list=EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
```

Comment: It seems like these kind of playlists have a limit of 20 videos, more videos are silently removed